# What is the best way to check if an objectid exists in an array field that holds all the objectids within a document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a document like this :

```
{ 
  subscriptions: [ 5cdf062b4a068f0b30cb9f18, 5afb062b4a068d9b41ab8c55, ... ],
  _id: 5d6a3d0bead1c01844ec4c75,
  email: 'papa@example.com',
  user_name: 'Papa Roche' 
}
```

A user can have many subscriptions but i doubt it will ever reach a number greater than a million.
Now i want to check if a subscription id already exists. What is the best way to go about it? Do i use array functions to loop through the contents of subscriptions field or do i use mongoose to query the db and see if this id exists in the field? Please give an example and slightly elaborate as well.

Comment: there is js method .includes() , you can use that to check if id exists or not

Comment: Pretty broad question...but in general: databases are usually faster and more efficient at queries/searching than can be achieved with JavaScript array functions.

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi well includes() always returns false for some reason, probably has something to do with subscription id's being mongoose objectId's.

Comment: Okay , if you could provide some ids and also what id you are looking for , may be we can check further!

Answer (score 0):

You would probably better off restructuring your schema such that the value of the subscriptions field is an object, not an array. this way you will have constant time lookup of a given subscription id. so what you currently have would change to:

```
{
  subscriptions: { 5cdf062b4a068f0b30cb9f18: {...subscriptionData}, 5afb062b4a068d9b41ab8c55: {...subscriptionData}, ... },
  _id: 5d6a3d0bead1c01844ec4c75,
  email: 'papa@example.com',
  user_name: 'Papa Roche' 
}
```